# play video in iOS + youtube url + objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, avkit

To play a video using `AVPlayerViewController`, the  code below works well:

```
-(void)openVideo{
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"];
    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];
    AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController new];
    playerViewController.player = player;
    [self.view addSubview: playerViewController.view];
    playerViewController.view.frame = self.view.frame;
    [player play];
    [self presentViewController:playerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Now I am getting the url like this:

```
<div class="first-video"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8aMHGC6A5zc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

How to play this kind of (youtube) url in AVPlayer?

Comment: it is the I frame you cant play in AVPlayer, in here you go for UIwebview or ytplayerview

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik  [Youtube helper](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper) has method `loadWithVideoId`. Where can I pass the I frames?

Comment: you can extract video id from your source url and pass it to 'loadWithVideoId' method. in your current src 8aMHGC6A5zc is the video id.

Comment: I don't want to extract the video id because in future the video url might get change to another source. 
@Anbu.Karthik, I am currently checking that is there any way to read the contents of url. So that if a url contains a video url, then play it automatically. Is it possible?

Comment: no is not possible, it is the Iframe,

Comment: else go with uiwebview,

Comment: else u need anything

Comment: @pkc456 - shall i delete my answer if it is not useful

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, Wait, I am working

Comment: @pkc456 - ok if you need the support ask me,

Comment: @pkc456 - your problem is resolved or not

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, Not yet. I am working on other issue as of now. BTW your answer is also very informative.

Comment: ok if you need the support ask me

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, the java script was not working because it is embedded inside the collectionview cell which again encapsulated inside tableviewcell. I resolve the problem by ejecting the collection view cell. I also [wrote tutorial on this](http://www.programmingcrew.in/2017/03/play-youtube-video-in-ios-app.html). Thanks.